# jQuery click on Appended Element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array. I am getting data from Array and using it in jQuery Append to list. But when I am clicking on list item its only showing the last element.

```
var array = [[1,2,7],[3,4,8],[5,6,9]];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var firstVal = array[i].[0];
    var secondVal = array[i].[1];
    var thirdVal = array[i].[2];

    var list = "<div class='divClass' <p class='class1'>"+ firstVal +"</p>"
             + "<p class='class2'>"+ secondVal +"</p></div>";
    $("#myDiv").append(list);
    $(".divClass").on('click', function(){
        alert(thirdVal);
    })
}
```

When I am clicking on each item it always shows the last value of `thirdVal` that is 9. How can I get the Third value dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the event handler outside the `for` loop and persist the arbitrary data with element using `.data(key, value)` which can later be retried using `.data(key)` in the current element context.

Additionally, You have syntax error while retrieving array elements

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 7],
  [3, 4, 8],
  [5, 6, 9]
];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //Rectify syntax errors while reading 
  var firstVal = array[i][0];
  var secondVal = array[i][1];
  var thirdVal = array[i][2];

  var list = "<div class='divClass'><p class='class1'>" + firstVal + "</p>" + "<p class='class2'>" + secondVal + "</p></div>";
  $(list).data('item', thirdVal).appendTo("#myDiv");
}


$(".divClass").on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).data('item'));
})
```

```css
.divClass {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

---

Or, use `let` instead of `var` and bind element handler to element then append it to list. A good read [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable)

```js
var array = [
  [1, 2, 7],
  [3, 4, 8],
  [5, 6, 9]
];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  //Rectify syntax errors while reading 
  var firstVal = array[i][0];
  var secondVal = array[i][1];
  let thirdVal = array[i][2];

  var list = "<div class='divClass'><p class='class1'>" + firstVal + "</p>" + "<p class='class2'>" + secondVal + "</p></div>";

  $(list).on('click', function() {
    console.log(thirdVal);
  }).appendTo("#myDiv");
}
```

```css
.divClass {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `this` in the click function to refer to the current item clicked from list:

```
 $(".divClass").on('click', function(e){
var index = $(this).index();
var text = $(this).text();
        alert('text: ',text, 'index: ',index);
e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Expect this help you.

tks

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the event outside for loop

```
var array = [[1,2,7],[3,4,8],[5,6,9]];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var firstVal = array[i].[0];
    var secondVal = array[i].[1];
    var thirdVal = array[i].[2];

    var list = "<div class='divClass' <p class='class1'>"+ firstVal +"</p>"
             + "<p class='class2'>"+ secondVal +"</p></div>";
    $("#myDiv").append(list);

}
    $(document).on('click','.divClass', function(){
        alert(thirdVal);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
var $list = "<div class='divClass' <p class='class1'>"+ firstVal +"</p>"
                 + "<p class='class2'>"+ secondVal +"</p></div>";
$("#myDiv").append($list);
$list.on('click', function(){
    alert(thirdVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [[1,2,7],[3,4,8],[5,6,9]];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var firstVal = array[i].[0];
    var secondVal = array[i].[1];
    var thirdVal = array[i].[2];

    var list = "<div class='divClass' <p class='class1'>"+ firstVal +"</p>"
             + "<p class='class2'>"+ secondVal +"</p><p style='display:none' class='thv"+i+"'>"+thirdVal+"</p></div>"; // change here
    $("#myDiv").append(list.cloneNode(true)); // Clone the node here
    $(".divClass").on('click', function(){
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName("thv"+i)[0].innerHTML); // change here
    })
}
```

If you didn't clone a node before append, the same node will be added. If you cloned it, it will create a copy every time.
Now check it.
Also there is a problem that you are alerting thirdVal. It will store the last value.
So, create an object with style `display:none` and add third value to it.
Then use `alert(<theobject>.innerHTML);`